# Kendo UI does not call the READ call

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am having an issue where the READ operation for the Kendo Grid does not get invoked and hence the grid does not populate any data. I have followed these links

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/troubleshooting#the-ajax-bound-grid-does-not-populate

[Kendo UI Grid is not calling READ method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300102/kendo-ui-grid-is-not-calling-read-method)

However the issue still exists.

/// CS File

```
public ActionResult GetItemsHome([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request , int page)
        {
            List<CustomItem> lst = new List<CustomItem>();

            return Json(lst.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

///cs html file

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CustomItem>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.No).Width("15%");
        columns.Bound(o => o.ShortDesc).Width("15%");
        columns.Bound(o => o.Category).Width("6%"); 
    })               
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(p=>p.Refresh(true))
           .Filterable()
           .Scrollable()
           .Editable(edit => edit.DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Are You Sure To Delete This ").Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
    .ColumnMenu(col=>col.Sortable(false))
    .Groupable()
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    //.ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()            
        .PageSize(6)
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetItemsHome", "det"))  
        .Model(model => {
            model.Id(p => p.ID);                   

            })

                .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "det"))
                  //  .Read(read => read.Action("EditingInline_Read", "Default1"))
                    .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "det"))
                    .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "det"))

 )
)
```

the order in which the JS is loaded

Any ideas ? 
Thanks

Comment: This is actually @Stargazer's comment, 'IS the action being hit at all? I mean, if you put a breakpoint int there, does it stop?'

Comment: Hi, do you get the solution in your question? then write here.

Answer (score 0):

Your action `GetItemsHome([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request , int page)` requires page (non-null value) to be passed. You have 3 options:

1. Delete this argument (this makes sense since `request` contains everything you want)
2. Supply it like: `.Read(read => read.Action("GetItemsHome", "det", new { page = 10}))`
3. Make it nullable like: `int? page`

EDIT: After following any of above, return some data from controller action (I am creating some arbitrary data, you may return it from DB instead) to fill up your grid. Something like:

```
public ActionResult GetItemsHome([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request , int? page)
    { 
       //List<CustomItem> lst = new List<CustomItem>();
       // Dummy data
       var data = new [] { new CustomItem(){ No = 1, ShortDesc = "xyz", Category = "abc"},
                           new CustomItem(){ No = 2, ShortDesc = "xyz", Category = "abc"} };
       return Json(data.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

If your controller and action names are spelled correctly in view, above code should work.

Comment: I have made the  action method nullable ( also tried removing the page param ) but the action method is not being called.

Comment: Sorry I am late. Is that all code inside your `GetItemsHome()`? You are not supposed to get anything since you are returning simply empty `lst`. Fill `lst` with `CustomItem`s and call extension on that.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities, if your function is not being called:

- If your ActionResult Index() function is doing some other operations instead of simply `return View()` and exiting, it's possible your GetItemsHome() function may not be called - I had this issue once.
- Try just naming the function "Read" instead of "GetItemsHome".
- Does your controller have any other functions (i.e. Update, Destroy)?  I would comment them out, in case there are syntax issues in them that are causing the issue.
- "det", I hope, is the name of your controller.
- Why pass in the extra page parameter at all?  Try it without it, and use a public variable in your model to hold that value.